# Loop that will create new Pandas.DataFrame column

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

Following the [scikit-learn tutorial here](http://scikit-learn.github.io/scikit-learn-tutorial/general_concepts.html#handling-categorical-features), if we have a `Pandas.DataFrame` that has a column named `colors`, how can we create a loop to loop through all of the DataFrame's columns (or a list containing the required columns) so that all categorial variables (eg. variable `colors` that can have values `blue`, `red`, `purple`) will be replaced by `len(colors)` number of dummy variable columns `colors#blue`, `colors#red`, `colors#purple`?

Just learnt python, so I'll write my idea in some psuedo code.

**Attempt (psuedo code)**

```
cols_to_process = ['colors']

# Create new columns for dummy variables
// if listings.keyname in cols_to_process:
    // unique_values = list of unique values in listings[col]
    // listings = listings.join(unique_values, axis=1)

# Populate dummy variable columns

# Remove old columns that have dummy variable columns created
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pandas.get_dummies` function to do that:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.get_dummies(listings['color'], 'color')
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you have a column that has values of a bunch of colors and you want to change those values all to the length of that column? This will do that:

```
df['column_name'] = len(df['column_name'])
```

If that's not what you want, please make your question more clear